# Possible error in NSMutableAttributedString

Tags: swift

I am trying to change the font of an label with should be displayed in the UI. I've used this lines:

```
let myAttribute = [ NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "cirth1", size: 18.0)! ]
        let buttonTitleNSMut = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "\(buttonTitle)", attributes: myAttribute )
        let buttonTitle:String = "\(buttonTitleNSMut)"

        let button = createButtonWithTitle(buttonTitle as String)
```

But my output isn't the label in the different font, but a long string with all the "specs" of the font...
What am I doing wrong? Maybe the fact that in the end I say it is a `String`?

Comment: Have you tried inspecting or printing to console the string you use, `"\(buttonTitle)"`? Does it have the text you expect?

Comment: Yes, the problem isn't the ' "\(buttonTitle)" '

Answer (score 0):

Try the code snippet below for what you are trying to achieve.

```
   let plainText = "\(buttonTitle)" as NSString
   let attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: plainText as String)

   attributedText.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "cirth1", size: 18.0)!)
   button?.titleLabel?.attributedText = attributedText
```

Hope that helps.